# Refactoring a text to have an array of time in and time out

Tags: php

This is the data that I exported from biometrics, and somehow, it is in a format of .txt:

```
UDISKLOG    version=2   date=2019-02-21 firmware=FK254HS30_en_v132
No  Mchn    EnNo        Name        Mode    IOMd    DateTime    
000001  1   000000001   ting            268435456   2305    2019/02/16  10:15:56
000002  1   000000001   ting            268435456   2305    2019/02/16  13:45:58
000003  1   000000001   ting            268435456   2305    2019/02/16  13:46:04
000004  1   001500022   julie           268435456   2305    2019/02/16  13:48:52
000005  1   000000001   ting            268435456   2305    2019/02/21  17:33:16
000006  1   000000001   ting            268435456   2305    2019/02/21  18:14:15
000007  1   001500022   julie           268435456   2305    2019/02/21  18:14:55
000008  1   000000002   marielle        268435456   2305    2019/02/21  18:18:15
000009  1   000000001   ting            268435456   2305    2019/02/21  18:52:54
000010  1   000000002   marielle        268435456   2305    2019/02/21  18:53:31
000011  1   000000002   marielle        268435456   2305    2019/02/21  18:55:57
000012  1   000000002   marielle        268435456   2305    2019/02/21  18:56:07
000013  1   001500022   julie           268435456   2305    2019/02/21  20:42:36
000014  1   000000001   ting            268435456   2305    2019/02/21  21:00:23
000015  1   000000001   ting            268435456   2305    2019/02/21  21:02:21
000016  1   000000001   ting            268435456   2305    2019/02/21  21:11:09
```

Somehow, I managed to convert it into arrays of only important details through this block code:

```
$file = file('GLG_001.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$data = [];

unset($file[0]);
unset($file[1]);

foreach($file as $files){
    $explode = explode(' ', $files);

    $first_explode = preg_split('/\s+/', $explode[0]);

    $data['student_id'][] = $first_explode[2];
    $data['time'][] = end($explode);
    $explode1 = $explode[count($explode) - 3];
    $second_explode = preg_split('/\s+/', $explode1);
    $data['date'][] = $second_explode[count($second_explode) - 1];
}

print_r($data);
```

Which then resulted into this:

```
Array
(
[student_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000000001
        [1] => 000000001
        [2] => 001500022
        [3] => 000000002
        [4] => 000000001
        [5] => 000000002
        [6] => 000000002
        [7] => 000000002
        [8] => 001500022
        [9] => 000000001
        [10] => 000000001
        [11] => 000000001
    )

[time] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17:33:16
        [1] => 18:14:15
        [2] => 18:14:55
        [3] => 18:18:15
        [4] => 18:52:54
        [5] => 18:53:31
        [6] => 18:55:57
        [7] => 18:56:07
        [8] => 20:42:36
        [9] => 21:00:23
        [10] => 21:02:21
        [11] => 21:11:09
    )

[date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2019/02/21
        [1] => 2019/02/21
        [2] => 2019/02/21
        [3] => 2019/02/21
        [4] => 2019/02/21
        [5] => 2019/02/21
        [6] => 2019/02/21
        [7] => 2019/02/21
        [8] => 2019/02/21
        [9] => 2019/02/21
        [10] => 2019/02/21
        [11] => 2019/02/21
    )

)
```

Notice that there are the same student IDs in the array, those are the times the student entered his/her biometric into the system. The first unique ID means that it his/her time in and his/her last ID means time out. In the given array, the student ID `000000001` is in the key `[0]`, and his last ID is in the key `[11]`. Compare it to the `$data['time']`, his/her time in is `[0] => 17:33:16` and his/her time out is `[11] => 21:11:09`. After identifying the the time in and time out, I want to store it into an array. So the `$data['student_id']` will then be converted into an array with unique values through `array_unique()`, consequently, store the time in and time out into an array too with the same count with the `count(array_uniqe($data['student_id']))`. So the final output would be:

```
Array(
[student_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000000001
        [1] => 001500022
        [2] => 000000002
    )
[time_in] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17:33:16
        [1] => 18:14:55
        [2] => 18:18:15
    )

[time_out] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21:11:09
        [1] => 20:42:36
        [2] => 18:56:07
    )
[date] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2019/02/21
        [1] => 2019/02/21
        [2] => 2019/02/21
    )
)
```

However, i do not know of what to do on the last part, getting the time in and time out.

Comment: In the last array of final out I think you have written wrong details please check it... that is confusing us...  000000001 his in time should be 17:33:16 but you have written 10:15:56

Comment: even the date is also wrong 2019/02/16 it should be 2019/02/21

Comment: ohh sorry, you're right sir. Lemme update my post

Comment: Maybe you can search an array in reversed order?

Comment: what do you mean sir ?

Comment: It's a long complicated answer, I'm trying to write a code for you, If I can.

Comment: The array you want looks complicated and hard to use. Why not make a nested array with each studentID as the key? That way you can easily find all data on one student in one subarray

Comment: @Andreas, I haven't had a single thought of that sir, but nice idea! I'll put in my project :D Thank you sir :D

Comment: @Andreas but how will he make it :P he will still needs a help

Comment: @MarielleMaeValdez :P try the othersolution, andreas told you and I will do it what you want

Comment: @MarielleMaeValdez I have done it but when I have finally done it I found out that you have given me the wrong array  of student_ids

Comment: and another scenario you will face later on in case any student forget to do in time or out time... this will mess up your array...

Answer (score 0):

```
$student_id = array("000000001",
     "000000001",
     "001500022",
     "000000002",
     "000000001",
     "000000002",
     "000000002",
     "000000002",
     "001500022",
     "000000001",
     "000000001",
     "000000001"
    );

$time = array("17:33:16",
        "18:14:15",
        "18:14:55",
        "18:18:15",
        "18:52:54",
        "18:53:31",
        "18:55:57",
        "18:56:07",
        "20:42:36",
        "21:00:23",
        "21:02:21",
        "21:11:09"
    );

$date= array("2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21",
        "2019/02/21"
    );


    $newArr = array_unique($student_id);
    $newRevArr = array_reverse($newArr);
    $time_reverse = array_reverse($time);
    $date_reveres = array_reverse($date);

    foreach($newArr as $key=>$value) {
        echo $value ." signed in: ". $time[$key]." signed out: ".     $time_reverse[$key] ."<br .>\n";
    }
```

Result:

```
000000001 signed in: 17:33:16 signed out: 21:11:09
001500022 signed in: 18:14:55 signed out: 21:00:23
000000002 signed in: 18:18:15 signed out: 20:42:36
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multidimensional associative array based on student ID and date with this loop.
The code creates an array with the structure `$arr[ID][date][time]`

```
$arr = array_slice(explode("\n", $data),2);
foreach($arr as $line){
    $temp = preg_split("/\s+/", $line);
    $result[$temp[2]][$temp[6]][] = end($temp);
}
```

This results in:

```
array(3) {
  ["000000001"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["2019/02/16"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "10:15:56"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "13:45:58"
      [2]=>
      string(8) "13:46:04"
    }
    ["2019/02/21"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "17:33:16"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "18:14:15"
      [2]=>
      string(8) "18:52:54"
      [3]=>
      string(8) "21:00:23"
      [4]=>
      string(8) "21:02:21"
      [5]=>
      string(8) "21:11:09"
    }
  }
  ["001500022"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["2019/02/16"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "13:48:52"
    }
    ["2019/02/21"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "18:14:55"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "20:42:36"
    }
  }
  ["000000002"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2019/02/21"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "18:18:15"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "18:53:31"
      [2]=>
      string(8) "18:55:57"
      [3]=>
      string(8) "18:56:07"
    }
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/uX0ig
You can also add the name in to the array like this:
https://3v4l.org/BbWid

---

If you only want to output the in and out times then you can loop the result array as follows:

```
foreach($result as $student => $subarray){
    echo $student . " " . $subarray['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    unset($subarray['name']);
    foreach($subarray as $date => $val){
        echo 'date ' . $date . ' sign in ' . $val[0] . ", sign out " . end($val) . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This results in:

```
000000001 ting
date 2019/02/16 sign in 10:15:56, sign out 13:46:04
date 2019/02/21 sign in 17:33:16, sign out 21:11:09


001500022 julie
date 2019/02/16 sign in 13:48:52, sign out 13:48:52
date 2019/02/21 sign in 18:14:55, sign out 20:42:36


000000002 marielle
date 2019/02/21 sign in 18:18:15, sign out 18:56:07
```

Comment: this is a bit hardcore on my level of knowledge hahaha

Comment: But using multidimensional associative arrays will make most projects much easier to use. Try the link above and let's say you want to find everything about student ID 000000001. You just `print_r $result[000000001];` and there is all the data collected and sorted for you.

Comment: @MarielleMaeValdez I have updated my answer with an output code.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that you want to get the student's "first in_time" and "last out_time".

I think putting date and time separately in to different array makes it more difficult. So it is better to put time and date together when you reading file in to array. 
Later on you can separate date and time easily.

If I understand your problem correctly, It seems you just need to find min and max index of an array which are first in time and last out time for every students.

I write little code and result below. Hope this will help you.

// Note that I put date and time together.

```
<?php

// Array given 
$ar_data['student_id'][0] = '000000001';
$ar_data['student_id'][1] = '000000001';
$ar_data['student_id'][2] = '001500022';
$ar_data['student_id'][3] = '000000002';
$ar_data['student_id'][4] = '000000001';
$ar_data['student_id'][5] = '000000002';
$ar_data['student_id'][6] = '000000002';
$ar_data['student_id'][7] = '000000002';
$ar_data['student_id'][8] = '001500022';
$ar_data['student_id'][9] = '000000001';
$ar_data['student_id'][10] = '000000001';
$ar_data['student_id'][11] = '000000001';

$ar_data['time'][0] = '2019/02/21 17:33:16';
$ar_data['time'][1] = '2019/02/21 18:14:15';
$ar_data['time'][2] = '2019/02/21 18:14:55';
$ar_data['time'][3] = '2019/02/21 18:18:15';
$ar_data['time'][4] = '2019/02/21 18:52:54';
$ar_data['time'][5] = '2019/02/21 18:53:31';
$ar_data['time'][6] = '2019/02/21 18:55:57';
$ar_data['time'][7] = '2019/02/21 18:56:07';
$ar_data['time'][8] = '2019/02/21 20:42:36';
$ar_data['time'][9] = '2019/02/21 21:00:23';
$ar_data['time'][10] = '2019/02/21 21:02:21';
$ar_data['time'][11] = '2019/02/21 21:11:09';


// Restructure
// Get all in and out time 
foreach ($ar_data['student_id'] as $index => $value) {
    $ar_new[$value][] = $ar_data['time'][$index];
}

// Make a result array
foreach ($ar_new as $student_id => $ar_time_list) {
    $ar_result['student_id'][] = $student_id;
    $ar_result['time_in'][] = $ar_time_list[0];
    $count_time = count($ar_time_list) - 1;
    $ar_result['time_out'][] = $ar_time_list[$count_time];
}


echo "\nResult:\n";
print_r($ar_result);

?>
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Result:
Array
(
    [student_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 000000001
            [1] => 001500022
            [2] => 000000002
        )

    [time_in] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019/02/21 17:33:16
            [1] => 2019/02/21 18:14:55
            [2] => 2019/02/21 18:18:15
        )

    [time_out] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019/02/21 21:11:09
            [1] => 2019/02/21 20:42:36
            [2] => 2019/02/21 18:56:07
        )

)
```

Comment: Nice logic, sir :D Thank youuu!

Answer (score 0):

Almost done try it...

```
$data = Array
(
"student_id" => Array
    (
        "0" => "000000001",
        "1" => "000000001",
        "2" => "001500022",
        "3" => "000000002",
        "4" => "000000001",
        "5" => "000000002",
        "6" => "000000002",
        "7" => "000000002",
        "8" => "001500022",
        "9" => "000000001",
        "10" => "000000001",
        "11" => "000000001"
    ),

"time" => Array
    (
        "0" => "17:33:16",
        "1" => "18:14:15",
        "2" => "18:14:55",
        "3" => "18:18:15",
        "4" => "18:52:54",
        "5" => "18:53:31",
        "6" => "18:55:57",
        "7" => "18:56:07",
        "8" => "20:42:36",
        "9" => "21:00:23",
        "10" => "21:02:21",
        "11" => "21:11:09"
    ),

"date" => Array
    (
        "0" => "2019/02/21",
        "1" => "2019/02/21",
        "2" => "2019/02/21",
        "3" => "2019/02/21",
        "4" => "2019/02/21",
        "5" => "2019/02/21",
        "6" => "2019/02/21",
        "7" => "2019/02/21",
        "8" => "2019/02/21",
        "9" => "2019/02/21",
        "10" => "2019/02/21",
        "11" => "2019/02/21"
    )

);

//echo "<pre>";print_r($data);

$data["time_in"] = [];
$data["time_out"] = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data["student_id"]); $i++) {
    for ($j = (count($data["student_id"]) - 1); $j < count($data["student_id"]); $j--) {
        if ($data["student_id"][$i] == $data["student_id"][$j]) {
            array_push($data["time_in"], $data["time"][$i]);
            array_push($data["time_out"], $data["time"][$j]);
            unset($data["student_id"][$j]);
            unset($data["time"][$i]);
            unset($data["time"][$j]);
            unset($data["date"][$j]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";print_R($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete working code. It is always the best practice to store the data in a multidimensional array.

```
<?php
  $finalData = [];
  $file = array_splice(file('GLG_001.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES), 2);

  foreach($file as $files){
    $explodedData = preg_split('/\s+/', $files);
    $curTimestamp = strtotime($explodedData[6].' '.$explodedData[7]);
    $finalData[$explodedData[2]][$explodedData[6]][] = $curTimestamp;
  }
  foreach ($finalData as $studentId => $studentData) {
    foreach ($studentData as $date => $times) {
      sort($times);
      unset($finalData[$studentId][$date]);
      $finalData[$studentId][$date]['timeIn'] = date('H:i:s', $times[0]);
      $finalData[$studentId][$date]['timeOut'] = date('H:i:s', end($times));
    }
  }
  echo '<pre>'; print_r($finalData); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [000000001] => Array
        (
            [2019/02/16] => Array
                (
                    [timeIn] => 10:15:56
                    [timeOut] => 13:46:04
                )

            [2019/02/21] => Array
                (
                    [timeIn] => 17:33:16
                    [timeOut] => 21:11:09
                )

        )

    [001500022] => Array
        (
            [2019/02/16] => Array
                (
                    [timeIn] => 13:48:52
                    [timeOut] => 13:48:52
                )

            [2019/02/21] => Array
                (
                    [timeIn] => 18:14:55
                    [timeOut] => 20:42:36
                )

        )

    [000000002] => Array
        (
            [2019/02/21] => Array
                (
                    [timeIn] => 18:18:15
                    [timeOut] => 18:56:07
                )

        )

)
```